# Lens theory, what sets the angle of view in photography?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

Is this correct statement that - in photo equipment angle of view forms from dimensions of sensor i.e. if we draw line from top most and bottom most edge of the sensor trough center of the lens we get viewing angle.

In other words sensor acts like eye that looks trough the lens, so sensor's angle of view based on its size (provided the lens is same focal length)?

[image]

Comment: I don't know where you got that drawing from, but the illustration of the light rays is incorrect. This is a more correct picture: https://cnx.org/resources/275cfdaf11484cff7252d7c2a8ef568c/Figure%2026_06_08.jpg

Comment: OP's drawing is correct. He is not showing rays that form an image.

Comment: [Field of view and angular field of view](https://www.princetoninstruments.com/learn/camera-fundamentals/field-of-view-and-angular-field-of-view)

Answer (score 0):

Your diagram is correct as shown for a simple lens while in a real camera lens the line would go through the center of the aperture diaphragm. The diagram also illustrates the so called crop factor. A smaller sensor with the same lens would have a narrower field of view that would correspond to a longer focal length lens used with the larger sensor.